# How to retrieve data from backendless DB using Swift Async method?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, backendless

I'm trying to receive data from a backendless database in swift. The code throws a *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*.

```
func findPlayersByPosition(position: String) -> [Player] {

    let whereClause = "category = '\(position)'"
    let dataQuery = BackendlessDataQuery()
    dataQuery.whereClause = whereClause

    var error: Fault?

    let players = Backendless.sharedInstance().data.of(Player.ofClass()).find(dataQuery, fault: &error)

    if error == nil {
        print("Contacts have been found: \(players.data)") // **Fatal error is thrown on this line**
    }
    else {
        print("Server reported an error: \(error)")
    }

    var playerDB = players.data as! [Player]

    return playerDB
}
```

"players" does include data, so I think this error might appear because I'm using a synchronous method to retrieve players that is not yet completed when I call print(players.data). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So I'd like to use a asynchronous method to see if that solves the error. I've been digging through the [backendless documentation](https://backendless.com/documentation/data/ios/data_search_and_query.htm) which does explain how to do an Async call:

```
func find(_ dataQuery: BackendlessDataQuery!, responder responder: IResponder!) -> Void
```

But I still don't understand how to apply this method to my own code? Help greatly appreciated.

**Updated Question**

Thanks for the answers so far. I figured out that when I call the function from inside viewdidload() it works fine. However, when I call the function using a required init method in the viewcontroller like this:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    do {
        let players = findPlayersByPosition("GK")
    } catch let error {
        fatalError("\(error)")
    }
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Then players is still nill

Q1: Why doesn't this work from within the required init()?

Comment: have you tried debugging it with breakpoints? what are the contents of the variables present in the code.

Comment: Updated my question. The problem: My function does work when I call it from viewdidload() but not when I call it from a required init inside the viewcontroller. Any idea why not?

Comment: Same logic applies - no layout information present. If it works from viewDidLoad that is pure luck - it will not work on all devices, put every layout logic in the places it belongs, not in init or didLoad

Comment: I'm still learning about the layout logic. Looks like I have some more reading to do then. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

Your player object is probably nil (or players.data might be nil). Print it out before the if statement.

You can protect your code as follows:

```
if let players = players {
    if error == nil {
        print("Contacts have been found: \(players.data)") // **Fatal error is thrown on this line**
    }
    else {
        print("Server reported an error: \(error)")
    }
}
else {
    print("nil players object")
}
```

Seems like you should be calling Backendless asynchronously:

```
let dataStore = Backendless.sharedInstance().data.of(Player.ofClass())

let players = dataStore.find(dataQuery, 
    response: { (result: BackendlessCollection!) -> Void in

        // handle response here

    }, 
    error: { (fault: Fault!) -> Void in

        // handle error here

    })
```

https://backendless.com/documentation/data/ios/data_search_and_query.htm

Comment: players.data was nill because of a typo in the whereclause. Fixed that but still get an error  when trying to cast to [player]

at the line "var playerDB = players.data as! [Player]".

Any idea on how to solve that?

Comment: I don't know what type players.data is so I can only give you some guidance. You can't arbitrarily convert data to an array of some type of object.  What does Backendless say to do? Have you looked for docs or examples from them?

Comment: Yes they cast to an array in their docs themselves. I actually just got the function to work from within viewdidload() but it's still not working when I call it from within a required init inside the viewcontroller (see updated question).

Comment: Is the call to Backendless really synchronous?

Comment: It looks like this function does not include a responder handler: Backendless.sharedInstance().data.of(Player.ofClass()).find(dataQuery, fault: &error) whereas the async call signature in the docs does (see question). I've asked their support on how to solve this issue. Will post it here when I get the answer.